# Printing String with an edited character using array of char instead of creating a new String object

Tags: java, string

The objective of this code is to change the String "A Happy" to "A Hippy".

```
String originalStr = "A Happy";
char[] charOriStr = originalStr.toCharArray();
charOriStr[3] = 'i'; //simplified code, we are supposed to loop through the String
```

To print the revised String, I use:

```
System.out.println(charOriStr);
```

However the recommended solution is as below:

```
String revised = new String(charOriStr);
System.out.println(revised);
```

I'm a beginner and I'm not sure if I should follow the recommended solution as a best practice guideline? Appreciate some guidance on this, thank you.

Comment: why dont you use `replaceAll` method from `String`?

Comment: `for (char ch : charOriStr) System.out.print(ch); System.out.println();`

Comment: In your first code snippet, `revised` isn't defined. If you follow it directly by `System.out.println(revised);`, you will get an error saying `revised` is unknown

Comment: Sorry, it should be charOriStr instead or revised.

Comment: Makes sense ; then both work, but in one case you're printing a `char[]` that is implicitely cast to `String`, while in the other case you have constructed a new `String` which you print. If the goal is to obtain the revised `String`, you can't just have a `char[]` and say "it's ok, it's printed the same way"

Comment: Well, if you don't plan on using String's functionalities on your "char array". Feel free to loop through the char array and print it (case -1) . If you plan on using some String functions on that String later on (or pass it to a method that accepts a String), then convert it to a String.

Comment: @TheLostMind Doesn't even need to loop through. Just passing char array should work right ?

Comment: @SureshAtta - Yes, true that. `PrintStream`'s `print` methods take and flush char streams too :)

Comment: @Aaron it doesn't actually convert to String implicitly. It just prints the characters, by passing the character array to the underlying writer, which doesn't need to convert them to output them.

Comment: @thanuja did you actually try to do that?

Comment: @TheLostMind Just confirmed myself by looking at the source code ;)

Comment: @thanuja it won't work because charOriStr is of type char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whom so ever recommended is clearly wrong here. Since you already have char array in your hand, you doesn't need to convert that to String again, just to print. Because the `println` method you are using will convert your String again to a char array inside.

Comment: sorry that I'm unclear on your last statement. Could you elaborate on the statement 'the println method you are using will convert your String again to a char array inside.'?

Comment: @yogescicak I mean if you look at the internal implementation of println method again it converts the char[] to string before printing in to to console

Answer (score 2):

You could use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` and edit the same input instead of creating a new one.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("A Happy");
        str.setCharAt(3,'i');
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

---

**Bottomline:** Check out `StringBuilder`, there are lots of cool stuff you can do with it.

Answer (score 2):

A `char[]` is the implementation upto java 8. For String that can hold Unicode text for all scripts in the world, Latin, Arabic, Greek, Cyrillic and so on.

Keeping on the abstraction level of String is more ... *abstract*, and certainly fully completed.
If you want to substitute a coil in your car, you do not expect to receive it back as a collection of parts.

For instance `char` is a 2-byte value for UTF-16 encoding, one form of Unicode. Nowadays `int` values, so called *code points* have less irregularities. So you could have made the solution based on code points, and with that have handled Chinese too.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the logic here. Anyway String's will be formed with a char array internally. So the same problem will be encountered inside string. Isn't it ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SureshAtta `String`'s methods handle UTF-16 surrogates appropriately. Printing the characters one by one won't have the same effect as converting a whole string to `UTF-8` for printing.